# Exchange data between un-related (table)viewcontrollers?

Tags: objective-c, data-binding, delegates, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

I have a app with TabBar, under the main tabbar there are navigation controllers, under these there are 'branches' of tableviewcontollers.

How can I make two unrelated, non segue-connected, under two different tab icons viewcontrollers exchange information between them?

Tried with delegating but I can't get the instance variable to the delegator from the delegatee (there's no relation between them, no segue.destinationviewcontroller etc)

any ideas?

practical:
the app shows list of subitems (the parent tableview has the items), andon the other tab the recent items that were selected are getting added (but maxiumum 10 and sorted by most recent).. been breaking my **** on it...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered posting an `NSNotification`, passing the data you want to transfer in `userInfo`?

From the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Notification.html):

> The object sending (or posting) the notification doesn’t have to know
>   what those observers are. Notification is thus a powerful mechanism
>   for attaining coordination and cohesion in a program. It reduces the
>   need for strong dependencies between objects in a program (such
>   dependencies would reduce the reusability of those objects).

The class sending a notification does it as follows:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: <notification-name> 
                                                    object: self
                                                  userInfo: <your-user-info>];
```

and the class listening for the notification registers for notifications using:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self 
                                         selector: @selector(someMethod:) 
                                             name: <notification-name> 
                                           object: nil];
```

and has a method:

```
- (void) someMethod: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSDictionary * myInfo = notification.userInfo;

    //do something with myInfo
}
```

Comment: Nope... can you describe the process? what's the correct way of doing it with NSNotification?

Comment: but can I pass an object such as NSDictionary as the data with this method?

Comment: Yes, you can pass any NSObject subclass as a parameter (using the **object** parameter of the *-postNotificationName:object:* method), so a NSDictionary or any other (custom) subclass of NSObject would work fine. Just remember to typecast the object to the correct class in the receiver. Personally I would like to add that personally I try to avoid using the NSNotificationCenter as much as possible, often other 'cleaner' solutions are possible, though this might mean changing the logic flow of the program.

Comment: The object: parameter of the postNotificationName: method is usually the object that posted the notification. The userInfo: parameter is of type NSDictionary, so would work for your needs, but per Wolfgang's comment, you could typecast it as required (or better yet, add any objects to a dictionary and pass as userInfo:)

Comment: Great stuff here! Thanks alot!! I'll investiage into that.
Only wondering: can an inactive non-visable ViewController can act as a NSNotification Observer? Is so, where (in the controller lifecycle functions) should I register it?

Comment: Register for notifications in your view controller's init method, and don't forget to add a call to removeObserver: in its dealloc method.

Answer (score 2):

I find `NSNotification`s not the best way to do this since you do couple the unrelated TableViewControllers. I think the flow of information in an application is crucial.

The solution I would personally favor is having a central class, that manages the global data for your application. This can be the `AppDelegate` class or an arbitrary manager class that manages the flow of data and "pulls the strings" and mediates between the different independent ViewControllers.

**Example:**
Using this code you can get hold of your `UITabBarController` and set your class as the delegate of your ViewControllers etc.:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UITabBarController *rootTabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    MyFirstTableViewController *firstVC = [rootTabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
   firstVC.delegate = self; // Get informed about events in the first ViewController

    MySecondTableViewController *secondVC = [rootTabBarController.viewControllers lastObject]; // Assuming you only have two Tabs

    // Once you have the rootTabBarController you can cast it to the corresponding ViewController and access any nested UIViewControllers

    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - MyFirstTableViewControllerDelegate
-(void)firstTableViewController:(MyFirstTableViewController *)sender didSomethingFancy:(MyFancyObject *)fancy{
    // Do stuff like fetching some data, based on the event from the first ViewController
    // Maybe tell the secondVC to refresh its data etc. etc.
}
```

Comment: Great, only issue is that one of the viewcontrollers needing the data exchange is not on one of the root TabBar viewcontrollers but "buried" further down a navigation controller (under the TabBar).

Also where would be the best place/function to 'register' the delegate=self in that other viewcontroller?

Comment: this would clear things up:

[un-related viewcontrollers storyboard](http://imgbin.org/index.php?page=image&id=6254)

trying to connect 'top places photos' to 'recent photos'

Answer (score 1):

You can use @property and @synthesize to create default getters and setters. You can aso create your own getters and setters manually.

Comment: I know that. can't understand how that helps here.